# Should I reuse Microsoft.NET attributes for other reasons or should I create my own attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

Is it appropriate to use the attributes that Microsoft.NET provides for alternative uses or should I create my own attributes?

For example, I've often seen people use the `DescriptionAttribute` for enumerations as "friendly names". Though, my understanding was that the `DescriptionAttribute` was intended to be used by the IDE and for this reason.

Another example would be to use the `DefaultAttribute` to, through reflection, set all of the default values of properties during construction.

So, is it acceptable within best practices to reuse attributes in ways not normally intended?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't re-use attributes. I create my own custom ones.

This prevents me from using attributes and then getting unexpected behavior in the future when somebody uses my classes in a way that I didn't anticipate.

Answer (score 1):

the DefaultAttribute  and DescriptionAttribute  are used by the "propertygrid" control, which is the control used in the visual studio designer. it is also possible to use this control in your own code, and then it makes sense using these attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition MS provide, and create your own when they don't fit the official definition. Might sound silly to create your own (not that it's really long to create a new one), but if someone come to read your code and didn't read the 20 pages manual intitled "our alternative uses of official attributes", he will be all confused about what's going on.

Beside, lot of .NET classes check for those attributes. You can end up with very weird behavior if you misuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's own posted best practices have nothing to say on the subject, and the code usage on the [DescriptionAttribute MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) makes it clear that this built-in attribute is used in some other ways.  I would generally consider it very dangerous to add extra meaning to something that only has relevance in your project.  This is referred to as 'tribal knowledge' and is one of the major ways misunderstandings start when working with others.

If you have a use-case that is covered by the .NET framework, awesome - you should definitely use what's out there first.  But if you're not sure, it is probably best to simply create your own.